# Ways to see what configure parameters was QT built with

Tags: c++, qt, build

Any idea(s) on how to see what configure parameters where used in building QT?

Comment: Do you only have the libraries or do you have the source tree where configure was called? Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux OpenSuse, ready premade build. I didn`t build it.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible. If you really need to know, I guess you'll have to check all possible configuration option and verify them yourself

Comment: Some options you can guess based on what flags show up when you build a project. If you want to make sure you have things set up in a particular way, you could always build your own copy of the libraries in your home directory.